# Writing to file using properties

Tags: c#, properties, io

I'm trying to write to a file at the moment I create my HighScores object. I'm trying to use the Name and Score properties as the text to the file, but they seem to be null and 0 respectively even though I initialized the object. So my question is why is it not writing "David : 88 "?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{ 
   HighScores David = new HighScores() { Name = "David", Score = 88 };
}

class HighScores
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    private int score;
    public int Score
    {
        get
        {
            if (score < 50)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            return score;
        }
        set
        {
            score = value;
        }
    }

    public HighScores()
    {
        // Opening and writing to the file            
        FileStream fileStream = File.OpenWrite(path);
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileStream);
        writer.Write($"{Name} : {Score} \n");
        writer.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Andre correctly points out, the “Constructor” `public HighScores()` is called when you create a new `HighScores` object like you have below.

```
HighScores David = new HighScores() { Name = "David", Score = 88 };
```

Unfortunately the properties `Name` and `Score` have not been initialized. Since it is a “Constructor” simply pass the variables as you would a normal constructor like below:

```
HighScores David = new HighScores("David", 88);
```

Then set the matching signature in the `HighScores` “Constructor” then you can set the properties and it should work as expected, however I agree with Andre as this (writing to file) should be a separate method and NOT part of the “Constructor” Hope that makes sense.

```
public HighScores(string name, int score) {
  Name = name;
  Score = score;
  using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenWrite(path)) {
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileStream);
    writer.Write($"{Name} : {Score} \n");
    writer.Close();
  }
}
```

.

Comment: Good point. I had thought that the initializers ran at the same time as the constructor, but they run right after.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that the Constructor runs before any of the "sets" in your code. Setting breakpoints in your code (in your constructor, in the property sets) and using Step Into, might help see what order all the code is being run in.

So, instead of writing the values in the constructor, refactor that into an actual method.

change the line

```
public HighScores()
```

to

```
public void SaveScores()
```

then add the line after you "new" up your object.

```
David.SaveScores();
```

That should work.

I'd also look into leveraging the using/Dispose pattern as well.

```
using (var fileStream = File.OpenWrite(path))
{
  // do stuff
}
// dotNet will be sure to call Dispose and clean up the fileStream.
```